# How to apply a function interface which has properties as well?

Tags: typescript

How to apply the following interface?

```
interface Example<T> {
    (a: T): T;
    name: T | undefined;
}

const test: Example<string> = ???
```

I do not know what to assign to `test`. Have in mind I do not want to name the function included in the interface.
I found the above pattern in React:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
     (props: P, context?: any): ReactNode;
     propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
     contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
     defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
     displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to just do it in two steps, using the support for [property declarations on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions):

```
const test: Example<string> = a => a.toUpperCase();
test.name = "hey";
```

But if you want to do it in a single line you can do so via [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const test2: Example<string> =
  Object.assign((a: string) => a.toUpperCase(), { name: "hey" });
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbCAHgBUA+ZAbwChlkAKOALmWIEpniBuG5EbCDsgA+yAK4gAJhBigIE7gF8qVBAHsQAZzDJIW5hmz4iWqKADm5ALzI4yS+TgA6MKoCqOHNADCcDRDqs3LpgjnxYKNYARAAWEACekdwq6lo6EFoATPqYuASEJuZWPADyAEYAVhAIIb4awGYgdAzMBSBmrHYOzm4e3r7+rAA0lLz8zDHxkcgKgUA)